# Problems from macros have the same name

Tags: c, linux, qt, macros

In my project, this is already defined in `boost_log.h`:

```
#define LOG_INFO \
    if (_LOG_LEVEL >= 4) \
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) _LOG_LOCATION
```

This works fine. But recently, I have added a library which contains a header include `syslog.h` and it has `LOG_INFO` as well. Because of this conflict, I can't build the project.

Is there any elegant way to fix this? Rename isn't really an option, because the macro in `boost_log.h` is used almost everywhere by other devs, so I can't commit the renamed macro.

Comment: #undef LOG_INFO after including the respective header file. See if that works.

Comment: Is `#undef`ining the macro before including the header of the second library an option? That would mean that you can't use the macro, of course.

Comment: Please be more specific. The header of the new library contain `syslog.h`, stored in `/usr/include/sys/syslog.h`, I think change it sounds risky.

Comment: You don't have to touch the headers. You can undefine a macro with `#undef`. That macro will then be unavailable to your code, which might be a concern. Invocations of that macro in other modules will not be affected by an `#undef` in your code. After all, macro are just text replacements in the source code.

Comment: Hi, I'm unfamiliar with the macro thing, where should I put `#undef`. I want to use the macro in `boost_log.h` not `syslog.h`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the following set-up:

```
#include "one.h"    /* defines LOG_INFO */
#include "two.h"    /* defines LOG_INFO as something else -> clash! */
```

Both definitions are macros. Macro expansion is a step that happens before the compilation proper; the compiler only sees the preprocessed text.

You can delete macros that were defined with `#define` with the `#undef` directive:

```
#define SQUARE(X) ((X)*(X))

int x = SQUARE(8);      /* Expand to ((8)*(8)) == 64 */

#undef SQUARE

int y = SQUARE(17);     /* No expansion */
```

The last line is still legal C code, but it assumes that `MACRO` is a function and will complain if it isn't defined.

So, to cut a long story short, one solution to your problem might be:

```
#include "one.h"        /* defined LOG_INFO */

#ifdef LOG_INFO
#undef LOG_INFO         /* delete LOG_INFO macro */
#endif

#include "two.h"        /* legally define a fresh LOG_INFO */
```

In that case, you have only the definition of `LOG_INFO` from `two.h`. (The `ifdef` is just to make sure `LOG_INFO` was actually defined and to avoid an error with `#undef`.) That should remove the clash.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But AFAIK, I must put `#undef` right into `syslog.h` right after `LOG_INFO` is declared right?

Comment: No, you can `#undef` a macro anywhere after is was defined. For example, it can be useful to `#define` and `#undef` a macro inside the same function to implement a kind if scope. Try out my suggestion and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, unfortunately, it ain't work for me. Correct me if I'm wrong, I put `#undef LOG_INFO` right before `#include "boost_log.h", and Qt still complains about it :p

Comment: And the inclusion und `#undef` are after the Qt stuff? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Yes, `#include"boost_log.h"` was the last `#include` statement, right after `#undef INFO_LOG`. Basically, it complains about the input of the macro is wrong. We don't use the same parameters with `syslog.h`

Comment: So you're using the `LOG_INFO` from `syslog.h`? In that case, `#include "boost_log.h"`, then `#undef LOG_INFO`, which will disable Boost's version and then `#include "syslog.h"`.When you now invoke `LOG_INFO`, it's the one from syslog. You can only have one of both.

Comment: No, I want to use `LOG_INFO` from `"boost_log.h"` so I `#include...   #undef LOG_INFO #include "boost_log.h"`